# play.exceptions.JPAException: The JPA context is not initialized

Tags: guice, playframework-1.x

I have a bean, which access JPA in constructor, e.g preload cache from database.

On application starts up I receive

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to create Guice injector
```

Application startup fails cause of Guice injection

```
1) Error injecting constructor, play.exceptions.JPAException: The JPA context is not initialized.
 JPA Entity Manager automatically start when one or more classes annotated with the @javax.persistence.Entity annotation are found in the application.
```

The root cause of this issue, that Guice is creating instance of my bean before play inits  JPA entity manager. The rest JPA code works fine, if I comment JPA call in constructor of bean, it works fine too.

To configure my beans, using follow code snippet:

```
public class MainGuiceModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
             bind(UserManager.class).to(UserManagerImpl.class).in(Singleton.class);
              ...
        }
}
```

The question is, how to access JPA from constructor using Play! and Guice ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I found the way how to avoid this exception, I have to wrap creation of injecor with

```
play.Play.plugin(JPAPlugin.class).startTx(true);
```

and

```
play.Play.plugin(JPAPlugin.class).closeTx(false);
```

I will accept answer with more elegant solution